# How to embed custom HTML code with no plugins?

Tags: posts, embed

I'm trying to embed this code into a post:

```
<script src="http://www.stokerposter.com/swfobject.js"></script>
<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" width="422" height="750">
    <param name="movie" value="http://www.stokerposter.com/Stoker_Poster_04.swf" />
    <!--[if !IE]>-->
    <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://www.stokerposter.com/Stoker_Poster_04.swf" width="422" height="750">
    <!--<![endif]-->
      <img src="http://www.stokerposter.com/Stoker_Poster.jpg" alt="" />
    <!--[if !IE]>-->
    </object>
    <!--<![endif]-->
</object>
```

But the result in the preview always falls back on the image, and the comment tags `<!--` are visible for some reason. Is there any way to embed this without a plugin?

Thanks

Comment: by "no plugins" - you mean no PHP code?

Comment: I mean no plugins for embedding HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are using the Visual side of the editor.

[image]

**You need to use the Text side.**

[image]

Get it?

### Update:

Preview won't show embedded objects. Publish it privately if you absolutely must see it before anyone else, and need to see embedded bits like `<object>` tags.

### Update #2:

Preview will show many embedded objects now as of WP 4.0. And many embeds can occur from merely a URL (tweets, youtube, for example).

Comment: Nope, I'm suing the Text side of course.

Comment: i updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

I think WP is making assumptions about what you're inputting into the editor. Try disabling its automatic paragraph tagging.

http://davidwalsh.name/disable-autop